# be notified in a page that another window is closed in asp .net web application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Using aps.Net 3.5 Web Form c#

In one of my pages(say `pageA`), there is a button `btnDo`.

When I click the button, a new window opens(say `winA`). few tasks are done there. after finishing tasks, the window(`winA`) closes automatically.

At that time, in my `pageA`, I want to be informed that `winA` is closed already.

Is it possible? I am wondering for two days.

Comment: what to try? i am loking for a hint.

Comment: How much hint do you need? Create an html page, open it with window.open and try what will work and what doesn't.

Comment: if u don't have a hint, don't try to apply. I have tried far more than that.

Comment: Maybe it becomes more productive for the both of us if you share what you have *tried far more than that*?

Comment: Yes this is possible, look at something like signalr

Answer (score 0):

Browser window has link to a window which opened it (window.opener), so you can hook to the page's beforeupload event and call function in pageA:

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() 
{ 
    if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed && window.opener.notifyWinAClosed) {
        window.opener.notifyWinAClosed();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can communicate over cookie betwen that two pages.

Comment: necessary data are stored in session. but I have to catch the time when the new window is opened.